# How do I store dynamically a movieclip in a array in Haxe/HTML5?

Tags: arrays, html, flash, movieclip, haxe

This is my code:

```
var buttons:Array<Dynamic> = new Array<Dynamic>();
var mc2:flash.display.MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc2.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
mc2.graphics.moveTo(50,50);
mc2.graphics.lineTo(100,50);
mc2.graphics.lineTo(100,100);
mc2.graphics.lineTo(50,100);
mc2.graphics.endFill();

buttons.push(addChild(mc2));

buttons[0].x = 1000;
```

And my question is why this work in Flash but not work in HTML5 when I compile it? How do I solve the problem?
The last line “buttons[0].x = 1000;” is not working in HTML5… :/

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1):

Because you use in "flash.display.MovieClip" class that does not available from HTML5.

In Haxe, if you use in class that belongs to specific target (like MovieClip) you can compile it only to that target.
Maybe you will found OpenFl library useful, It's library that let you develop with Flash API and target to almost any device(and also for HTML5) from same base code!

see [Here](http://www.openfl.org/learn/) for more

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework?
Maybe it works if you split the `addChild` and the `push` into separate lines? Not sure if `addChild` returns a MovieClip?

Otherwise, try to trace the array `trace(buttons)` and observe the browser console.